# Pandas: split an Excel column populated with a dropdown menu into multiple dataframe columns and isolate typos

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following column in Excel, which was populated by using a dropdown menu. However, some entries were added disabling the macro and typing the responses manually. This created some typos.

```
      Answers
0     Yes       #correct
1     No        #correct
2     no        #typo - manually entered
3     noo       #typo - manually entered
4     yeah      #typo - manually entered
5     Yes, No   #correct (multiple entries are allowed)
```

I want to be able to create a new dataframe where I keep the original column "Answers", but I want to append three more columns: "Yes", "No", "Typos".
"Yes" and "No" will have `1` if their value is present, `0` otherwise. The "Typos" column should contain everything that is not included in the accepted list of answers in the form of a string, and it is to be assigned `0` if there is no typo.

Example output:

```
      Answers   Yes    No    Typos
0     Yes       1      0     0
1     No        0      1     0
2     no        0      0     no
3     noo       0      0     noo
4     yeah      0      0     yeah
5     Yes, No   1      1     0
```

My attempt consisted in identifying the unique entries of the "Answers" column like this:

```
all_answers = df['Answers'].str.get_dummies(', ')
```

This is how I create the additional columns:

```
accepted_ans=['Yes','No']
idx=1
for i,name in enumerate(all_answers.columns.tolist()):
    if i>0:
        if name in accepted_ans:
            df.insert(idx+i, name, all_answers[name])
```

And this is how I manage the "Typos" column:

```
df['Typos']=0 #Create empty column with all zeros
for i in range (0, len(df)): #Iterate over the rows
    if df['Answers'].iloc[i] not in accepted_ans:
        df['Typos'].iloc[i]=df['Answers'].iloc[i]
```

My problem: the "Typos" column is full of zeros, e.g. either the `if` statement above fails or the line below that. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(answers=['Yes', 'No', 'no', 'noo', 'yeah', 'Yes, No']))
def typos(l):
    probs = [e for e in l if e not in ['Yes', 'No']]
    return ', '.join(probs) if probs else 0
>>> df.answers.str.split(', ').apply(typos)
0       0
1       0
2      no
3     noo
4    yeah
5       0
Name: answers, dtype: object
```

In case your column is mixed-type (i.e., not all entries are strings), you might need to first convert it to a sting, i.e.,

```
df.answers.astype(str).str.split(', ').apply(typos)
```

Comment: What's that `l` for? I get an error pointing at that line saying that 'float' object is not iterable.

Comment: That means you're passing it a float for some instance. Try `df.answers.astype(str).str.split(', ').apply(typos)`.

Comment: Cool, this works. Can you please explain what happened, and perhaps amend your answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: In fact I should have mentioned that my real column is mixed-type.